# Algorithm for understanding behavior of arrays

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

You are given a list of size N, initialized with zeroes. You have to perform  M operations on the list and output the maximum of final values of all the  N elements in the list. For every operation, you are given three integers a,b and  k and you have to add value  to all the elements ranging from index  to (both inclusive).

**Input Format**

First line will contain two integers N and M separated by a single space.
Next M lines will contain three integers a,b  and k  separated by a single space.
Numbers in list are numbered from 1 to N .

Constraints
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNnyx.png)

**Output Format**

A single line containing maximum value in the updated list.

**Sample Input**

> 5 3
>   1 2 100
>   2 5 100
>   3 4 100

**Sample Output**

> 200

**Explanation**
After first update list will be  100 100 0 0 0.
After second update list will be 100 200 100 100 100.
After third update list will be 100 200 200 200 100.
So the required answer will be 200.

**One of the Solutions with less time complexity**

```
n, inputs = [int(n) for n in input().split(" ")]
list = [0]*(n+1)
for _ in range(inputs):
    x, y, incr = [int(n) for n in input().split(" ")]
    list[x-1] += incr
    if((y)<=len(list)): 
        list[y] -= incr
max = x = 0
for i in list:
    x=x+i;
    if(max<x):max=x
print(max)
```

Can someone explain the above solution?

Comment: Is this an *active* programming contest?

Comment: No.This a practice problem from hackerrank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it stores deltas rather than the final list; that means each operation only takes 2 reads and writes rather than (b - a + 1). Then the final `max` scan adds the deltas as it goes along, which is still an `O(n)` operation which you would have had to do anyway.

```
n, inputs = [int(n) for n in input().split(" ")]
```

Get the list size (n) and number of operations (m), ie `5` and `3`

```
list = [0]*(n+1)
```

Create an empty 0-filled list. Should be `lst = [0] * n` (do not use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in type) (we do not need an extra end cell, except as a checksum on our algorithm - if it works properly the final checksum should be 0).

```
for _ in range(inputs):
    x, y, incr = [int(n) for n in input().split(" ")]
```

Get an operation (a, b, k) ie `1`, `2`, `100`.

```
    list[x-1] += incr
```

Add delta to the starting cell

```
    if((y)<=len(list)): 
        list[y] -= incr
```

Subtract the delta from the ending cell (should be `if y < n: lst[y] -= incr`)

The algorithm may be easier to understand if you add a `print(lst)` here (after the `if` but inside the `for` loop).

Now process the deltas to find the maximum item:

```
max = x = 0
for i in list:
    x=x+i;
```

`x` is now the value the actual value of the current list cell. Also `max` is a terrible variable name because it shadows the built-in `max()` function.

```
    if(max<x):max=x
```

Keep a running max tally

```
print(max)
```

Show the result.